# Remove padding in Google Bar Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I need a simple bar chart with only one percentage bar and labels. I'm trying to remove the padding between the bar and the total canvas with 'chartArea' but the result it's not the expected, anyone knows how i can do that?

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/rro74054/1/>
```

I set a 'tomato' background color to make the space more visible.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please add some more description. Didn't get what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your options...

```
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '100%'
    },
```

Example...

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRightY);

function drawRightY() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['', 'name1', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'name2', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'name3', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],
    ['', 50, '50', 100, '100', 150, '150']
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '100%'
    },
    chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'tomato'},
    isStacked: 'percent',
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: false,
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10,
        auraColor: 'none',
        color: '#fff'
      }
    },
    legend: 'none',
    enableInteractivity: false,
    hAxis: {
        baseline: 0,
        gridlines: { count: 0 }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```